# Burned / black pizza stone

Tags: cleaning

Placed pizza stone in 525f oven to preheat.  Smoke pouring out.  Opened window, exhaust & even the bathroom exhaust.  Thought it would quit eventually.  Put pizza in oven for approx 8 min.  Smoke still billowing... removed pizza with stone.  Stone as black as charcoal. Inside of oven, including window on door, soot coated everything.  Pizza turned out great!  Read on Pinterest & other sights, to put stone in oven on self cleaning cycle would work.  Was going to shower when I saw blue flames through the oven door. The damn stone was on fire!  Shut the self cleaning cycle off.  Scared the crap out of me!  What happened?

Comment: Pizza stone hardly used.  Had no food residue whatsoever.

Comment: Wait, did you cook the pizza on the "self cleaning cycle"?

Comment: What brand stone was it?

Comment: Reminder: Comments are not for answers, half-answers or similar. See [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.

Comment: Not a baking stone. Maybe for cutting or serving.

Comment: Afterwards did the stone look damaged: melted? (That would mean not a baking stone or even ceramic) Pitted/cracked? (could be caused by localised heating, localised contamination) I'm wondering if it could have got contaminated with oil - that would smoke at baking temp but ignite on self cleaning - how/where was it stored?

Comment: you removed it from the packaging first?  j/k..... I have no clue what happened here. Post an image if you can.

Comment: Also, did it smell like food smoke (and even then, burnt toast or oil?), plastic smoke, paper smoke, or what?

Comment: Stone made from Alberta oil shale? I would not use a stone that smoked liked that. The black stuff is an oxidized hydrocarbon mix which belongs nowhere near something you are about to eat.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually scrub it off with steel/copper wool or some other soft abrasive. You're likely just burning off stuff that got stuck on it. Honestly, if its not flecking off with your finger, you can just cook with it. avoid water however

Comment: If you do clean it with water, put it in an oven at about 80C for a couple of hours, starting when it looks dry, then increase the temperature gradually.  It's rapid heating to above boiling point with trapped moisture that breaks them

Comment: i recommend just air drying it if you get it wet

Comment: at first yes, and after just a rinse, but the inside dries really slowly without heat. So if its been immersed, to be sure it's dry you need to do something more. A few days in a warm place should do, but in that case you'd better start with it really clean or risk mould. Better to heat it gently.